# Is there a way to join Google Hangouts without a Google+ account?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

One of my friends insists that I should use Google Hangouts because it's so much better than Skype. I would like to give it a try, but I wouldn't like to create a Google+ profile for that. Is there *any* way (some website or URL hack, Android application, some third party desktop software that hacks it's way into the system) to try it without creating a profile?

Comment: Try it with a completely fake profile. If your concern is privacy, then that's a solution. If your concern is the time it takes, then just creating a new account is a lot shorter than logging onto StackExchange, posting a question, reviewing the answers and taking action on those answers.

Comment: Right. My only problem with that solution is, that I think I'll find it good, and I would probably want to use it in the future  too. But I probably won't find it good enough to make a profile for it. (And yes, privacy is my concern.)

Comment: It's not possible to use Hangouts without a Google+ profile. To create that profile you need to go through phone verification. So if you're worried about privacy, forget it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a feature that has been introduced in the year since the question was asked, but it appears that you can use a limited version without a Google+ account via Gmail chat according to [this support article](http://support.google.com/chat/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=161986):

> If you don’t have a Google+ account you can start or join a limited hangout, which only includes the option to hang out with 1 other person. If you’d like access to all Hangouts’ features including the ability to hang out with up to 9 people, share your screen, and use cool Hangouts’ apps, you can upgrade to a free Google+ account

This sounds similar to what [Korey](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/44456/16377) has encountered and what [Freedom](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42718/16377) tried to suggest.

This answer presumes you have GMail/Google account, but not a Google+ one. Unfortunately Google seem to be closing off their systems, highlighted by the [discontinuation of XMPP support](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Google-s-chat-client-drops-Jabber-compatibility-1866129.html).

Answer (score 2):

It appears Hangouts on my Android phone works without a Google+ account, but many features such as photo sharing are disabled.

Hangouts for Chrome browser extension insists on creating a Google+ account.

Things could change.  I do not like how Google is pushing all users to Google+.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about your privacy, create a fake profile - name it something your friends would recognize or even the opposite of what your friends would recognize or random letters.

In the end, creating the profile isn't a big deal and it gets you better access to your friends: pretty good payoff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. You have to have a Google+ account to join hangouts!! 
Update: But you can use a limited version. For more information [John C's](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/44564/12738) answer.

Comment: -1. No longer always true. See [John C's answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24751/is-there-a-way-to-join-google-hangouts-without-a-google-account#44564) to this question. I wonder if you could please delete your answer, since it's obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to join Google+
You can use Hangouts video chat 1on1 with regular Google account
Joining Google+ you get up to 9 people in video chat